# Большой расход памяти

Tags: c++, linux, boost, asio

Есть сетевое приложение основанное на `qt + boost asio` под ос `linux 64 bit`. При запуске размер занимаемой оперативной памяти составляет порядка 20Mb, но в процессе работы на каждый создаваемый сокет программа вырастает в среднем немного менее чем на 1Mb, и итоге с 300-ми активными соединениями объем занимаемой памяти достигает ~250Mb.

`sizeof` самого дочернего класса соединения в иерархии не превышает 10кб. Объект сокета особо не содержит каких либо больших объемов данных.
В приложении всего 7 потоков, 6 из них обработчики `boost::io_service`.

Такого же не должно быть?
В чем может быть причина такого большого потребления памяти?

Comment: Вам стоит использовать профилировщик памяти.

Comment: а кроме того с подобными вопросами в доказательство стоит приводить статы ps'а дабы исключить недопонимание новичком разницы между виртуальной памятью и резидентной...

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` не показатель реального размера памяти, который необходим для работы объекта. `sizeof` покажет лишь общее кол-во байт, выделенных на стеке при размещении объекта на том же стеке. Если в процессе работы производится динамическое выделение памяти через `new`, то этот размер не отразится в `sizeof`, но вполне будет заметен при просмотре через менеджер памяти ОС.

Пример:

```
struct S
{
    S() : p(new int[10000]) {}
    int* p;
};
```

`sizeof(S)` даст размер указателя (8 или 4 байта) в зависимости от разрядности ОС. Но эффективный размер объекта типа `S` будет существенно больше, т.к. в конструкторе выделяется ещё массив в куче.

Answer (score 1):

Использование профилировщика показало что большую часть памяти в куче выделяет CRYPTO_malloc и CRYPTO_realloc. Теперь есть над чем подумать...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008145/valgrind-shows-memory-leak-in-ssl-after-closing-the-connection

Comment: я использую boost asio, а не openssl (или какие то там библиотеки ssl напрямую)...

Comment: И как это меняет то, что описано по ссылке?